# "Close" vs. "closed"

Tags: word-choice

Doors in and out of an apartment complex have a sign attached that says "Please keep door close at all times". I say it should say "Please keep door closed at all times".

Am I correct?

Comment: Most likely. There's nothing ungrammatical about *keep door close at all times*, but it means that you should keep the door ***close by you*** at all times. (I.e. carry it around with you.) I can't imagine that being the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are asking you to stay near to the door(unlikely), this is a typo.

> Please keep the door closed at all times

Except for when you're going through it obviously (or is it a fire door only for use in fires?)

or:

> Please make sure to close the door

You can use close here as it's an instruction to close it, rather that keep it close.